# How would data be dynamically queried in rust

Tags: rust

Say there is an user that wants to query a random element during runtime from a dynamic struct. The type of the data is unknown, but all the data is either a integer (size unknown), float, string, or vector of one of the aft-mentioned structs, and the struct implements the `queryable` trait, which mandates that the struct have get methods for all of the data the user is allowed to query.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Rust has no run-time reflection capabilities, so you'll have to implement your own infrastructure for dynamic introspection. You will also likely want the results of such a query to be serializable, and/or to follow a simpler data model (e.g. the JSON data model).

For example, we might define:

```rust
enum Value<'a> {
  Queryable(&'a dyn Queryable),
  Json(serde_json::Value),
}

trait Queryable {
  fn query<'a>(&'a self, fieldname: &str) -> Option<Value<'a>>;
}

impl Queryable for Value {
  fn query<'a>(&'a self, fieldname: &str) -> Option<Value<'a>> {
    match self {
      Queryable(q) => q.query(fieldname),
      Json(json) => json.as_object()?.get(fieldname).cloned()
    }
  }
}

struct Root {
  foo: Foo,
}

impl Queryable for Root {
  fn query<'a>(&'a self, fieldname: &str) -> Option<Value<'a>> {
    match fieldname {
      "foo" => Some(Value::Queryable(&self.foo)),
      _ => None,
    }
  }
}

struct Foo {
  bar: f64,
}

impl Queryable for Foo {
  fn query<'a>(&'a self, fieldname: &str) -> Option<Value<'a>> {
    match fieldname {
      "bar" => Some(Value::Json(self.bar.into())),
      _ => None,
    }
  }
}
```

Then, a nested object access `root.foo.bar` could be conducted via this model as `root.query("foo")?.query("bar")`.

Implementing your own introspection infrastructure can be tiring, especially since a lot of it could be automated using proc-macros. I recommend looking into [`async_graphql`](https://docs.rs/async-graphql/) which has to solve similar problems, as well as Rust-based template engines (though most just use Serde to serialize the objects into a simpler data model). Note that while Serde might make it possible to run some queries over a data model by writing a custom serializer, it doesn't really provide convenient introspection abilities.